# Return user if exists or create new

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to implement a view in Django/DRF that given a body containing `facebook_id`, `first_name`, `last_name` and `email`, the function checks if a user already exists in the database with either the `email` or the `facebook_id`. If not, then I create a new user and save it.

I'm trying to do this with a serialzier and I'm not sure what the correct approach is. I want to use the same serializer I used for sign ups which is this:

```
class ClientSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        exclude = ['password']
```

It contains a lot of unnecessary fields that I wont need in this new view (such as phone number). Should I create a new seralizer just for this view? Also should I depend on the `is_valid()` function on the serializer to tell me if the user exists (if it raises an error) or is that too unreliable since the fields might be invalid?

Here's what I have so far:

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def facebook_login(request):
    print(request.data)
    serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
       # create a new user
    else: 
        # possibly perform a get on the database to return the existing user?
    return Response(serializer.errors)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this.

```
@api_view(['POST']) 
def facebook_login(request): 
    print(request.data) 
    serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.Meta.read_only_fields = ['x', 'y'] 
    if serializer.is_valid(): 
        # create a new user 
    else: 
        # possibly perform a get on the database to return the existing user? 
    return Response(serializer.errors)
```

The read only fields will be a list of fields that you don't want the user to use on creation, but you still want to be in the view on retrival.

Comment: But as I said I write these fields in the sign up views

Comment: I don't really understand how to use this. Would it be better to create a separate serializer?

Comment: It could be, but imo it's nicer to have fewer serailzers. Especially for the same model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this,

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def facebook_login(request):
    print(request.data)
    data = request.data
    serializer = ClientSerializer(data=data)
    email = data.get("email")
    obj = Client.objects.filter(email=email)

    if obj.exists():
        return obj

    elif serializer.is_valid():
       f_name = data.get("first_name")
       l_name = data.get("last_name")
       email = data.get("email")
       # more that you need
       Client.objects.create(first_name=f_name, last_name=l_name, email=email, .....)
       return # whatever you want

    else:
        # whatever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it in the following way

```
api_view(['POST'])
def facebook_login(request):
    client = None

    email, fbid = request.data.get('email',None), request.data.get('facebook_id', None)

    # Assuming that email or facebook id is provided, not both

    if email is not None and Client.objects.filter(email=email).exists():
        client = Client.objects.filter(email=email).get()
    elif fbid is not None and Client.objects.filter(facebook_id=fbid).exists():
        client = Client.objects.filter(facebook_id=fbid).get()
    else:
        serializer = ClientSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            client = serializer.save()
        else:
            return Response(serializer.errors)

    return Response(ClientSerializer(instance=client).data)
```

It can be probably simplified in some way, but this would be my approach.